# Aptly : "gpg: no default secret key", but key isn't expired

Tags: gpg

I have good not expired gpg secret key but when I run

```
aptly -architectures=all publish repo product
Warning: publishing from empty source, architectures list should be complete, it can't be changed after publishing (use -architectures flag)
Loading packages...
Generating metadata files and linking package files...
Finalizing metadata files...
Signing file 'Release' with gpg, please enter your passphrase when prompted:
gpg: no default secret key: secret key not available
gpg: signing failed: secret key not available
ERROR: unable to publish: unable to detached sign file: exit status 2
```

Why?

Comment: Does your secret key have a passphrase?

Comment: I am not sure about aptly, but it is saying "no default secret key". Are you sure your non-expired good key is the default and that gpg knows where to look for it? Also, as icarus has pointed out, it is asking for your passphrase... if you do have it passphrase protected, aptly may not know how to handle that, and that would cause failure.

Comment: @icarus secret key have no passphrase

Comment: @number9 I have no idea what is "being default" for a gpg key? How to set up the default key? secret key have no passphrase

Answer (score 1):

Aptly uses gpg1, you need to create a key with gpg1.
This solved it for me :

```
gpg1 --gen-key
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).